# How do i add a row to my asp.net repeater from JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, repeater

I have a repeater in my code behind, which already has a list to it, now i have added a new row to the database table that holds the data the repeater displays on the webform via plain web services, and this works fine.

Assuming my web service method returns a list to my ajaxSuccess response, How do i update my repeater with the new list, or how do i just add the new row to the UI within the ajaxSuccess method. Here is the method below.

```
function UpdateUserServices(selectedService, userId) {
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PresentationService.asmx/UpdateUserServices",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({'selectedService': selectedService,
        'userId': userId
    }),
    success: function(response) {
    //add new row to the asp.net repeater before closing dialog
        $(".dvAddServices").dialog("close");
    },
    error: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: When the data comes down, does it contain all the rows or just the new ones? If it's all the rows, are the new ones marked as such?

Comment: Adding a row to a table at client side is not difficult. The main question is what you plan to do after adding the row, because it won't persist when you post back to server.

Comment: @mason which is the best approach, i think returning only the row(s) is ideal, why are you asking this ? does it have to do with the way it's added to the repeater?

Comment: @Win The row is saved n the database, therefore i need it to reflect in the UI and remain there unless i choose to remove it again. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: Returning only the new rows is best, since the rows that are already in the database already exist on the client end. Do you use postbacks? If not, then it should be very simple, and either or the two answers should work. If you

Comment: @ifelabolz **Who added that new row?** Normally, after adding a new record to database, the page renders records back to the client browser along with the new record. **Your approach is not common in ASP.Net Web Form** *(although we normally do that in ASP.Net MVC)*. What are you trying to do in general so that we can suggest you an alternative solution.

Comment: @Win I have added 2 rows to the database manually... so those 2 rows reflect in the UI when i load the page... now if i add a new item through the  UI as i expect my users to do, it will call this service method then a webmethod which then calls a DAL method to add the new item to the DB table. That's the usual thing to do, now the new row will not reflect on the page unless i log in and log out again, that way the postback is false, but i want the new row to reflect as soon as i have added it to the table

Comment: @ifelabolz Basically, you are inserting and selecting data via Ajax manually without using ASP.Net Web Form Ajax. Look like **you are fighting with the technology** - Web Form. That kind of scenario **you should consider using ASP.Net MVC**.

Comment: @Win i dont understand what you're saying, maybe you dont understand me... I have a JQuery ajax call to my web services...becuase i use jquery dialogs for my editing... well its too late to use mvc now.. thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

Like This ,

```
 success: function(response) {
var data = response.data;
var tC = new Array(); //TableContent
tC.push('<tr class="row" >');
tC.push('<td class="r">' + data.ID + '</td>');
tC.push('<td class="r">' + data.ID + '</td>');
tC.push('<td class="r">' + data.ID + '</td>');
tC.push("</tr>");
var html = '';
for (var i = 0; i < tC.length; i++) {
html += tC[i];
}
$(".table").append(html);
$(".dvAddServices").dialog("close");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer with out using arrays will be

```
success: function(response) {
var data = response.data;
      mytable = $('<table Class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
   var firstrow = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
            $('<td></td>').text('Entity Name').appendTo(firstrow);
            $('<td></td>').text('Attribute Name').appendTo(firstrow);
     $.each(data , function (i, obj) {
   var row = $('<tr></tr>').appendTo(mytable);
     $('<td valign="middle"></td>').text(obj.ID).appendTo(row);
  $('<td></td>').html("<div id='div1' >" + Obj.Name + "</div>").appendTo(row);
});
```